# Gitlab API services using nodejs

Tags: node.js, gitlab

I am trying to create nodejs utility program to access Gitlab of my company and display list of projects. 
Below steps were taken.

Step-1 : I created a simple nodejs with typescript project using step mentioned from a website [click here](https://blog.sourcerer.io/a-crash-course-on-typescript-with-node-js-2c376285afe1).

Step-2 : Installed Gitlab npm and referred article as given npm website [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitlab).

Step-3 : Wrote a simple typescript (gitcon.ts) given below and execute command `ts-node gitcon.ts`

On executing **gitcon.ts** i am getting error "unable to verify the first certificate". The complete error trace is given below heading 'nodejs_error'.

On Gitlab npm website (Step-2 link) they have mention proper way is to pass certificate like below but when i run 'npm start' command give throw error '**NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command**,'

```
"start": "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./secrets/3ShapeCA.pem node bot.js"
```

I am not quite sure if I can directly execute command 'ts-node gitcon.ts' or have to run 'npm start'. Let say apart of 'lib' folder (as mentioned in Step-1 website) in same location/project path, if I create a 'cert' folder and put my company cert say 'mycompany.crt' into the 'cert' folder what changes should i make in above "start" syntax (in package.json file) so that https call gitlab works without cert or handshake error.

**gitcon.ts**

```
import { Gitlab } from 'gitlab';

const api = new Gitlab({
  host: 'https://gitlab.mycompany.org',
  token: '1234567891011',
});


//console.log(api.Projects.all);

api.Projects.all().then(projects => {
    console.log(projects);
  });
```

**nodejs_error**

```
(node:4844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://gitlab.ets.org/api/v4/projects failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\project\others\ts7\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Comment: Setting an environment variable like NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS the way you try to does not work on the regular Windows command line, this is unix-style syntax. Being on a Mac, which doesn't have this issue, I don't know how to fix it, but I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for quick response. I tried setting windows path using 'set', as mentioned in site => https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/issues/87 but it did NOT work. Also, came up with a command "start": "C:/gitlab/cert/myco.pem ts-node gitcon.ts" to meet windows path, that did not work (first param is .pem path, 2nd is ts command (ts-node) , 3rd is filename).  Also executing command like 'npm start' and 'ts-node gitcon.ts' does not work and throws the same error. Not sure how to set exact command & required path so Gitlab npm can pick certificate (.pem) correctly